Forgot to include implication rate in grant proposal
I just submitted a project to ANR (French research grant fund), but I realized I forgot to mention my implication rate (i.e., the percentage of time dedicated to the project).
This is a grant for a single partner (me), so naturally my actual involvement will be substantial.
The deadline has passed so I cannot modify it. How grave is this mistake ? Can they automatically block a good quality fully written scientific proposal, just because this detail is missing?
Just asking for some advice from people with similar experiences.

The people at the ANR might be worth checking with.

Your chance of getting a valid answer here are vanishingly small. It is probably a rare mistake and we don't have all that many users with such experiences. You can and should try to ask them. While it would seem odd to reject an application when they can ask for clarifications, I don't know their rules or workload.

There's really just one thing you can do, and that is ask the folks at the funding agency.
Short of that, the proposal is sent and there is nothing you can do about it until it comes back with a decision. So kick back and relax, put your mind to other endeavors, and be productive in the areas where you can achieve something. It's not worth worrying about submitted proposals and papers because there's just nothing that worrying can affect.
